# Problems with Div Class Background Color Change with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm doing a little experimenting with using php for loops to generate a massive amount of divs that can be altered through JQuery changes to their css. The riddle I'm trying to solve right now is generating a checkerboard, a series of square black and white divs, which upon click will swap colors. I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around how the onClick event is looking at the situation.

Here is where I got stuck

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .yes { background: black; 
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        float: left;
        }
  .no { background: white; 
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        float: left;
        }  

  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        $j = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
        if ($j == 0){
                echo "<div class = 'yes'>yes</div>";
                $j++;
            }
            if ($j == 1){
                echo "<div class = 'no'>no</div>";
                $j--;
            }
    }
  ?>

<script>
  var bw = 0;
  $(".no, .yes").one( "click", function () {
    if (bw == 0){
        $(".no" ).css( "background-color","black" );
        $( ".yes" ).css( "background-color","white" );
        bw++;
    }
        else {
        $(".no" ).css( "background-color","white" );
        $( ".yes" ).css( "background-color","black" );
        bw--;
        }


   });
    </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Some weird shift is going on where clicking some divs trigger the color change and other don't. 
If you guys have any interesting ideas please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){

          var bw = 0;
          $(".no, .yes").click(function () {
            if (bw == 0){
                $(".no" ).css( "background-color","black" );
                $( ".yes" ).css( "background-color","white" );
                bw++;
            }
                else {
                $(".no" ).css( "background-color","white" );
                $( ".yes" ).css( "background-color","black" );
                bw--;
                }


            }); 
         });

  </script>
```

whe you use `one()`

**Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element**

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: thats it. Thank you! Why does adding type="text/javascript" correct the problem?

Comment: you are welcome . look at this :) . http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('div').click(function()
{ 
    $('div').each(function()
        {
                if($(this).hasClass('yes'))
                   $(this).addClass('no').removeClass('yes'); 
                else
                   $(this).addClass('yes').removeClass('no');   
         });
    });
});
```

**check this too**